# how do I merge columns with the same header name by adding the data as a new row for that column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-transform

Given a table like this:

Before

[image: before]

How would I merge that so there are only 3 columns: a, b and c with extra data added as new rows? there could be more than a,b,c as column names.

I am trying to create the solution in Excel

I am trying to get it like this.

[image: result]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate solution:

`=LET(u,UNIQUE(A1:H1,1),VSTACK(u,DROP(REDUCE(0,TOROW(u),LAMBDA(a,b,IFNA(HSTACK(a,TOCOL(IFS(A1:H1=b,A2:H2),2)),""))),,1)))`

Comment: Again, got almost the same. I didn't utilize the `IFS` and used the `If(x,y,NA())` instead though (a lesson to remember). I couldn't figure out how it works correctly all the time. Then I realized that you're `IFNA`-ing the whole result on each iteration. I guess an improvement would be to put the `IFNA` before the `DROP` to do it only once on the final result. Also, the `TOROW` looks redundant!?

Comment: @VBasic2008 The IFS formula can only return values in case any of the conditions passed through the function are TRUE. In case nu TRUE is found it returns NA-error. The TOCOL with ignore argument 2 ignores these errors, so it only returns the TRUEs. In case of different length of spills for the different unique values it'll throw an error for the empty cells in the spill range when performing the HSTACK. So the IFNA is not on the errors of the IFS, but on the empty cells the stacking may produce. The TOROW around the unique values in REDUCE is indeed not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You may try-

```
=IFERROR(VSTACK(TOROW(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:H1))),DROP(REDUCE("",TOROW(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:H1))),LAMBDA(a,x,HSTACK(a,TOCOL(FILTER(A2:H2,A1:H1=x))))),,1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: `TOROW(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:H1)))` can be replaced with simply `UNIQUE(A1:H1,1)`.